# i need help sorting a array dynamically on column bases on the date match from string

Tags: arrays, sorting, date, vbscript

the array

```
myarray(uid,3/1/2016,3/4/2016,3/5/2016,3/6/2016,3/7/2016,3/8/2016
1,8,6,3,5,3,2
2,3,7,2,3,9,4
3,6,7,1,1,1,7
4,1,5,2,4,7,4
5,9,9,9,7,4,3
6,5,4,2,9,6,4
7,5,1,5,2,6,8
8,7,1,7,9,3,4
9,4,2,7,8,4,9
10,1,1,2,9,8,4)
```

the sample code im trying to work with

```
dim datearray
datearray(0) = "3/1/2016"
datearray(1) = "3/2/2016"
datearray(2) = "3/3/2016"
for var = lbound(datearray) to ubound(datearray)

needed code here
next
```

so im looking to match a date from array then sort on the column

Comment: You've completely changed the question now. Don't just tailor your question to one of the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a RegExp to get the portion of the string that appears to be the date and use the [IsDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48y0723t%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function to validate it.

```
Option Explicit
Dim myarray,i,MyDate
myArray=Array("3/1/2016","3/4/2016","3/5/2016","3/6/2016","3/7/2016","3/8/2016",_
"1","8","6","3","5","3","2",_
"2","3","7","2","3","9","4",_
"3","6","7","1","1","1","7",_
"4","1","5","2","4","7","4",_
"5","9","9","9","7","4","3",_
"6","5","4","2","9","6","4",_
"7","5","1","5","2","6","8",_
"8","7","1","7","9","3","4",_
"9","4","2","7","8","4","9",_
"10","1","1","2","9","8","4")
'Before sorting the array
WScript.Echo "Before sorting the array " & VbCrLF & VbCrLF & Join( myArray, vbTab )
Sort myarray 'Sort the array
'After sorting the array
WScript.Echo "After sorting the array " & VbCrLF & VbCrLF & Join( myArray, vbTab )

For i=LBound(myArray) to UBound(myArray)
    If FormatOutput(myArray(i)) <> "" Then
        MyDate = Mydate & FormatOutput(myArray(i)) & VbCrLF
    End If  
Next
wscript.echo MyDate
'*********************************************
Function FormatOutput(s)
    Dim re, match
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "[\d]+[\/-][\d]+[\/-][\d]+"
    re.Global = True
    For Each match In re.Execute(s)
        if IsDate(match.value) then
            FormatOutput = CDate(match.value)
            Exit For
        end if
    Next
    Set re = Nothing
End Function
'*********************************************
Sub Sort( ByRef myArray )
    Dim i, j, strHolder
    For i = ( UBound( myArray ) - 1 ) to 0 Step -1
        For j= 0 to i
            If UCase( myArray( j ) ) > UCase( myArray( j + 1 ) ) Then
                strHolder        = myArray( j + 1 )
                myArray( j + 1 ) = myArray( j )
                myArray( j )     = strHolder
            End If
        Next
    Next 
End Sub
'*********************************************
```

Comment: i having problom with the line
"For i10 = ( UBound( counterlist ) - 1 ) to 0 Step -1"
it says index out of range, here how i tried to apply the code

Comment: @demetriushenning rollback your changes. If you are going to show what you tried append to the original question don't replace it and lose the original context.

Comment: if figured it out in ur expl your using a 1d array my counterlist is 2d

Comment: @demetriushenning not according to your code, you are using a single dimension array not two.

Answer (score 1):

Recordsets can be filtered better than arrays and can sort themselves unlike arrays. This reads from standard in and writes to standard out. They can also save themselves to disk.

It creates a recordset in memory with two fields - a sortkey and a line of text.

It then loops through input and writes the sortkey extracted from the lines of text and the line into the recordset. Sets sort column. Loops through again writing the sorted recordset to standard out.

This differes from most use of a recordset as we create a disconnected one in memory rather than from a query on a database.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681510(v=vs.85).aspx

```
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
With rs
    .Fields.Append "SortKey", 4 
    .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
    .Open
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Lne = Inp.readline
        SortKey = Mid(Lne, LCase(Arg(3)), LCase(Arg(4)) - LCase(Arg(3)))
        If IsNumeric(Sortkey) = False then
            Set RE = new Regexp
            re.Pattern = "[^0-9\.,]"
            re.global = true
            re.ignorecase = true
            Sortkey = re.replace(Sortkey, "")
        End If
        If IsNumeric(Sortkey) = False then
            Sortkey = 0
        ElseIf Sortkey = "" then
            Sortkey = 0
        ElseIf IsNull(Sortkey) = true then
            Sortkey = 0
        End If
        .AddNew
        .Fields("SortKey").value = CSng(SortKey)
        .Fields("Txt").value = Lne
        .UpDate
    Loop
    If LCase(Arg(2)) = "a" then SortColumn = "SortKey ASC"
    If LCase(Arg(2)) = "d" then SortColumn = "SortKey DESC"
    .Sort = SortColumn
    Do While not .EOF
        Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: if u can shiw me how i would apply that itll help